# yacc/bison combined word problem

Tags: yacc, bison, lex

I have an if statement like the below

```
if false { expr }
```

It works, great! but i typed in

```
iffalse { expr }
```

and it works as well :| How do i fix that? the above should be a var name not an if statement

-edit-
nevermind i figured it out

Comment: You should add as an answer what your solution was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your lex file define a pattern similar to this

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

If you accidentally wrote this above the if pattern you should get an error about the pattern never being matched. Just put that pattern above and that problem will be solved